# Эффект растущей кривой polyline объекта?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность добиться эффекта, так называемой растущей кривой, реализуемый изменением значения `stroke-dashoffset`  с polyline объектом.

Приведу пример

```css
.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg_logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <symbol id="myLine">

    <polyline points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5" />
  </symbol>

  <use xlink:href="#myLine" class="st1" />
</svg>
```

Желательно средствами CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для любого объекта, имеющего атрибут `stroke-dashoffset`, можно получить эффект рисования линиями. То есть для всех фигур svg: `line`, `circle`, `ellipse`, `polygon`, `polyline`, `path`. 
Необходимо только точно вычислить длину этой линии. В вашем случае длина линии -`136px`

Ниже код утилиты для точного вычисления длины `<polyline>`
Для вычисления длины другой `polyline`необходимо скопировать значения `points`

```html
  <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
 <div>  
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" > 
 
         <polyline id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="1" 
         
   points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5" />
</svg>
</div> 
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

```css
#myLine{
fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
stroke-dasharray:136;
  stroke-dashoffset:136;
  animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% { 
   stroke-dashoffset:136;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
 }
```

```html
<svg id="svg_logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 60 200 200">
  <symbol id="myLine">

    <polyline  points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5" />
  </symbol>

  <use xlink:href="#myLine" class="st1" />
</svg>
```

Добавлю ещё два варианта:

### #1. Вариант с заготовкой пути

Это серый путь, по которому пойдет анимация рисования линии.
Используется та же линия, что и в первом примере, но она неподвижна. (`id="shadow"`)
Анимируется ее дубликат -`id="#myLine"`.

```css
#myLine{
fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
stroke-dasharray:136;
  stroke-dashoffset:136;
  animation:dash 4s ease-in 1s forwards;
}
#shadow{
   fill: none;
  stroke: #EAEAEA;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
   
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% { 
   stroke-dashoffset:136;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
 }
```

```html
<svg id="svg_logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 65 200 200">
  <symbol id="myLine">

    <polyline  points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5" />
  </symbol> 
   <symbol id="shadow">

    <polyline   points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5"  />
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#shadow"  />
  <use xlink:href="#myLine"  />
  
</svg>
```

### #2. Вариант с анимацей тени

Для получения тени клонируется первая линия и сдвигается  вправо и вниз на несколько пикселей

```
 <symbol id="shadow">
    <polyline  transform="translate(1 0.5)" points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5"  />
  </symbol>
```

анимация  линий выполняется совместно и  реализуется точно также, как в самом верхнем, основном примере для одной линии:

```css
#myLine{
fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
stroke-dasharray:136;
  stroke-dashoffset:136;
  animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
}
#shadow{
   fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
stroke-dasharray:136;
  stroke-dashoffset:136;
  animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
  opacity:0.5;
  
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% { 
   stroke-dashoffset:136;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
 }
```

```html
<svg id="svg_logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 65 200 200">

   <symbol id="shadow">
    <polyline  transform="translate(1 0.5)" points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5"  />
  </symbol>
  
  <symbol id="myLine">
    <polyline  points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5" />
  </symbol> 
  
  <use xlink:href="#shadow"  />
  <use xlink:href="#myLine"  />
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Приведение анимаций `CSS` и `SVG`

Этот ответ на вопрос, создаю специально для тех, кто  владеет приемами анимации CSS, но пока не  решается освоить анимацию SVG для расширения своих возможностей.
*Всё познается в сравнении.*
 Взят пример анимации CSS из первого ответа и я преобразую его в анимацию `SMIL` `SVG`

В основе эффекта рисования линии в обоих видах анимации (css и svg) лежит один и тот же прием - использование атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` - отступ от начала линии.
Когда максимальный отступ равен длине линии, то она полностью скрыта.
*Уменьшая `stroke-dashoffset` от максимального значения, в нашем случае - `136px` до нуля, мы тем самым реализуем эффект рисования, появления линии.*

SVG очень гибко и мощно работает со стилями,- делая анимацию `SMIL`, вы можете, как привыкли, внести `stroke-dasharray`,`stroke-dashoffset` в таблицу стилей или разместить стили прямо непосредственно в команде SVG.

```
   <polyline id="myLine"  points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5" 
 style="fill:none; stroke-width:4; stroke: #000; stroke-dasharray:136; stroke-dashoffset:136;"/>
```

Остается понять, как преобразовать анимацию `CSS`, в `smil`

Для CSS команда уменьшения `stroke-dashoffset` от 136px до нуля выглядит следующим образом:

```
#myLine{
 stroke-dasharray:136;
  stroke-dashoffset:136;
  animation:dash 5s ease-in forwards;
  } 
  @keyframes dash {
  0% { 
   stroke-dashoffset:136;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
 }
```

Для `SVG smil` аналогичная команда записывается так:

```
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="136" to="0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
```

вот, когда эти два способа (css, svg) рядом, то в принципе и так всё понятно. 
Добавлю лишь, что параметр`forwards` css  делает тоже самое, что `fill="freeze"` svg - изображение по  окончанию анимации замораживается на экране.

Ниже полный пример анимации `smil svg`

```html
<svg id="svg_logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 60 200 200">
   
    <polyline id="shadow"  points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5" style="fill:none; stroke-width:4; stroke: #EAEAEA; opacity:0.5;"  />
     
    <polyline id="myLine"  points="102.3,73.3 129.7,72.6 119.4,80.9 132.3,129 109.1,111.9 95.5,121.5" style="fill:none; stroke-width:4; stroke: #000; stroke-dasharray:136; stroke-dashoffset:136;"  >
 <animate  
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    from="136"
    to="0"
    dur="5s"
    fill="freeze" />
    </polyline>
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Иногда полезно узнать длину в рантайм, для этого в современных браузерах у `polyline` есть метод [`SVGGeometryElement.getTotalLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength), полученное таким образом значение устанавливаем в `stroke-dasharray`
первым аргументом, обозначающим длину штриха. вторым параметром идет размер между штрихами.

```
 line.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', line.getTotalLength() + ' 10000');
```

Анимация получается за счет встроенной интерполяции при добавлении в `css` `transition: 1s`

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 500" style="border: 1px solid">
<text x="20" y="40">Click anywhere to add point</text>
<polyline></polyline>
</svg>

<script>

let svgNs = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let line = document.querySelector('polyline');
let pt = svg.createSVGPoint(), pts = [];

svg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    pt.x = e.clientX;
    pt.y = e.clientY;
    var cur =  pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    pts.push([cur.x, cur.y]);
    
    let c = document.createElementNS(svgNs, 'circle');
    c.setAttribute('cx', cur.x);
    c.setAttribute('cy', cur.y);
    svg.appendChild(c);
    
    setTimeout(() => c.classList.add('show'), 1);

    line.setAttribute('points', pts.map(pt => pt.join(',')).join(' '));
    line.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', line.getTotalLength() + ' 10000');
   
});
</script>

<style>

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  transition: 300ms;
  opacity: 0;
  r:1;
}

circle.show {
  opacity: 1;
  r:10;
}

text {
  user-select:none;
  font-size:30px;
}

polyline {
  fill:none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width:3;
  transition: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

</style>
```

---

Кросс-браузерный вариант, со времен когда у polyline не было встроенного метода для того чтобы  узнать длину.

```js
let polyline = document.querySelector("polyline");
let totalLength = [...polyline.points].reduce((acc, i) => {
  if (acc.prev) 
    acc.len += Math.sqrt(Math.pow((i.x - acc.prev.x), 2) + 
                         Math.pow((i.y - acc.prev.y), 2));
  acc.prev = i;
  return acc
}, {len: 0}).len;

console.log('total length:', totalLength);
```

```css
polyline {
  fill:none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width:3;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" >
<polyline points="37.31343460083008,47.761192321777344 144.776123046875,14.925373077392578 238.05970764160156,58.208953857421875 335.8208923339844,20.149253845214844"></polyline></svg>
```

Comment: `у polyline не было возможности узнать длину`. немного не понял, что имелось ввиду. Добавил утилиту, для вычисления длины `polyline`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT раньше не было метода getTotalLength у polyline

Comment: мне кажется, что нужно заменить в твоем ответе `stroke-dasharray` на `stroke-dashoffset`

Comment: тогда немного подругому надо сделать, тут я анимирую именно значение размера штриха а не отступ